# White space because of DIV box, identify the problem but cannot solve

Tags: html, css

[image][image][image]

If the boxes are used with `overflow-x: hidden;`, the box will be cut off and it looks ugly.

I have attached the correct one, it should be intact that the box should not cross the right-side box.

```css
.row {
  width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.grid {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}

.grid:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.span-1-of-3 {
  width: 32.26%;
}

.span-2-of-3 {
  width: 66.13%;
}

.contact-form {

width: 60%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <form method="post" action="#" class="contact-form">

    <div class="row">
      <!-- left column -->
      <div class="grid span-1-of-3">
        <label for=>Name</label>
      </div>

      <!-- right column -->
      <div class="grid span-2-of-3">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your name" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Plz add some code.

Comment: Apologize since I am a beginner, please have a look.

Comment: Eric you have still not added any code...

Comment: You can edit the post from here: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66829529/edit)

Comment: OK now. Just added. ~~~

Comment: There are 20 boxes on your page, plz add a brief of what you have tried, and whats the problem. Your current provided code contains just two elements.. Add something so we can test...

Comment: You are using `it` in your sentences, how will we know which element are you targeting.

Comment: Sorry. let me explain more. The problem is at the right side. For each of the column , such as name, email ., etc total 6 boxes including send it. The right column of those boxes has extend so much that cross the div box. So that causing white spaces

Comment: This is the whole code of the project, please have a look  https://github.com/Erictse1/portfolio/tree/main/Omnifood%20practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is technically no problem.

```
.span-1-of-3 {
  width: 32.26%;
}

.span-2-of-3 {
  width: 66.13%;
}
```

`.span-2-of-3` is bigger than `.span-1-of-3` so it takes more space or you can say `.span-2-of-3` is double of `.span-1-of-3`.

---

## Solution

Make both of them equal, like `50%` or `49%` etc...

```
.span-1-of-3, 
.span-2-of-3 {
  width: 49%;
}
```

```css
.row {
  width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.grid {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}

.grid:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.span-1-of-3,
.span-2-of-3 {
  width: 49%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <form method="post" action="#" class="contact-form">

    <div class="row">
      <!-- left column -->
      <div class="grid span-1-of-3">
        <label for=>Name</label>
      </div>

      <!-- right column -->
      <div class="grid span-2-of-3">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your name" required>
      </div>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I have changed the span width for the first two boxes, but it seems the boxes are still  bigger than the div boxes.

Comment: @Eric Than Plz provide the complete code. You can add a link to codepen or edit your question.

Comment: I added to codepen. Please have a look.  https://codepen.io/erictse1/pen/MWJyZed

Comment: @Eric I can not see the right side boxes being overlapped or left side boxed being bigger and coming over the right side https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/BapKvQx

Comment: @Eric Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I try to include all relevant tag again,  https://codepen.io/erictse1/pen/MWJyZed.